# php foreach loop not looping to send emails only sending last record

Tags: php, email, loops, foreach

I am pulling emails out of a recordset.  They loop through and echo out correctly but am only sending to the last record?  What am I missing here?  It seems if it echos out the email it should be sending as well.  Thanks

```
  $query_email = "SELECT email FROM UserInfo";
 $email = mysql_query($query_email, $dandee123) or die(mysql_error());
 $numRows = mysql_num_rows($email);
 for ($count = 0; $count < $numRows; $count++){
     $row[] = mysql_fetch_array($email, MYSQL_ASSOC);

 }

$subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);

 $headers = "From: contact@xxxx\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To:  contact@xxx";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $message = '<html><body>';
 $message .= $_POST['messagesent'];
 $message .= '</body></html>';


foreach ($row as $email)
{
$to = $email['email'];

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//this works below but email only goes to last record?
    print "sent to ". $to;

 }
```

Comment: So you are saying that the `print to ".$to` shows chaning values as expected, but only one email gets delivered?  Have you looked at your mail delivery subsystem to see if the emails are stuck in the queue?

Comment: Correct!  The values change as expected but email goes to only the last address in the array.  Nothing stuck in the mail queue on my server....

Comment: What is the return value of the mail() function call?